# Mentally approximating an inverse sine?

Tags: trigonometry

Is there a method to approximate the inverse of a sine function in ones head?

I know one can approximate the inverse of a cosine with the following equation:

$\cos^{-1}(x) = \sqrt{7(1000-1000x)}-\frac{1}{2}$

Does a similar equation exist for inverse of sines?

Comment: $\sin(x) = \cos(x + c)$ ($c$ depending if radiants, degree or whatever). Hence, for the inverse (on appropriate domains): $\sin^{-1}(x) = \cos^{-1}(x)-c$.

Comment: Thanks- sorry for the following stupid question, it's been along time since I've taken trig; exactly what is c in that equation?

Comment: I don't know what unit you use. It's $\pi/2$ for radiants, $180$ for degree.